# How can i put a message like: "Do you want to proceed?" (yes or no) vba

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I have a code to add several rows on excel.
I would like make a code (vba) before that, in order to ask if it is to proceed in case we click in the button. It is to prevention.
How can I do that?
Someone can help me?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for problems solving, not a "classic" code learning site. If you tried something and have a problem, post your code here and you'll get help. From your question it seems you need to investigate and learn by yourself. [Read about what you need here](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/msgbox-function.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub qwerty()
    answer = MsgBox("Shall we continue?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Keep Processing")
    If answer = vbYes Then MsgBox "We will continue!!"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. It is very good, but it makes an error in the end. I write this code on the head of my code and without "Sub qwerty()" neither "End Sub", because in my code i have just had it. It work better but at the end it displayed an error.

Comment: The error displayed was: "Run time error "438" Object doesn`t support this property or method"

Answer (score 0):

I placed an Activex Button control from the tool box on the form then added the following code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim vbanswer As String
    vbanswer = MsgBox("OK TO PROCEED?", vbOKCancel, "ASK FOR USER RESPONSE")
End Sub
```

I dimensioned a string variable to place the response in. The message box asks " OK to Proceed?" and adds the two buttons for OK and CANCEL. When you type the comma after"OK TO PROCEED", Intellisense will supply you with all the choices for buttons. As you watch the Intellisense, it will also highlight in black what the current field is. 
Hope that helps.

Bill

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow !

Comment: Thank you, but i can`t use Activex Button because it doesn`t work on a Mac OS X. I have to use a form button and I this code doesn`t work. I think Activex button is much better than form button, but i can`t use.